# How to add audio feedback and take pictures?

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have a final year project about Face Mask Detection using tensorflow. I found this source code on internet and I want to add some functionality like audio feedback when someone is not wearing a mask and take a picture of them. How do I customize the code?

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np

category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(ANNOTATION_PATH+'/label_map.pbtxt')

# Setup capture
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

while True: 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    image_np = np.array(frame)
    
    input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
    detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)

    
    num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
    detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
                  for key, value in detections.items()}
    detections['num_detections'] = num_detections

    # detection_classes should be ints.
    detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

    label_id_offset = 1
    image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

    viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
                image_np_with_detections,
                detections['detection_boxes'],
                detections['detection_classes']+label_id_offset,
                detections['detection_scores'],
                category_index,
                use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                max_boxes_to_draw=5,
                min_score_thresh=.7,
                agnostic_mode=False)

    cv2.imshow('Face Mask Detection',  cv2.resize(image_np_with_detections, (960, 720)))

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're facing?

Comment: this site will not teach you programming, nor will anyone do your work for you. you should seek instruction elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

img_counter = 0

while True:
ret, frame = cam.read()

```
if not ret:
    print("gagal foto")
    break
cv2.imshow("selfie", frame)

k = cv2.waitKey(1)
if k%256 == 27:
    # ESC pressed
    print("pencet esc")
    break
elif k%256 == 32:
    # SPACE pressed
    img_name = "no{}.png".format(img_counter)
    cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
    print("{} written!".format(img_name))
    img_counter += 1
```

cam.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()